# how to use post methods without parameter in objective c

Tags: url, shopify

Hi I am using SHOPIFY api to create customer information, but there is no chance to pass parameters in this URL, so my question is that is it possible, by using POST methods can we create it?

Answer (score 0):

The ShopifyAPI documentation shows that it is a RESTful API. Therefore when you make calls to it, you use the appropriate verb(s). In the case of creating a resource, such as a customer, you use the POST verb.

A POST verb can include parameters, so your question is unclear. You do understand basic HTTP of course? If not, the Internet has many thousands of handy resources that clearly explain the HTTP verbs of interest.